# Image Path from ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, html, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I need some help for referencing the image present in the Ubuntu server. My image path in Ubuntu server "/home/Ubuntu/Chat/public/images/directions-icon.jpg". When i try to open the saved html its not displaying any thing. I thing its referencing my Laptop path. How to excursively mention a Ubuntu Path over here. Please Help Me. Thank you all.

My Code:

```
<html>
<img src="/home/Ubuntu/Chat-BOT/public/images/directions-icon.jpg">
</html>
```

Error: Not Displaying any thing

Comment: The path on the web is relative to the `DocumentRoot` setting of the web server. For security reasons you can't access arbitrary files.  The path is probably `/images/directions-icon.jpg`

Comment: @Cfreak if i keep '/images/directions-icon.jpg' again its try to access it from laptop

Comment: If it's on a different machine than the HTML page then you need to specify the host name.

Comment: @Cfreak In this way http://XX:XXX:XXX:XX/home/ubuntu/Chat-BOT/public/images.jpg

Comment: @Cfreak Should we need to add any port number to it?

Comment: If your server is using a port other than port 80 then yes. Your path is *still* wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the following things for diplaying the image

Ubuntu is a linux based operating system and its paths are case sensitive make sure you give exact path

Secondly their might be a permission issue for accessing the directory. You must atleast have read permission to show the image. Run "sudo chmod" command to change the permission of your desired directory.

Thirdly, make sure that the path you are giving is in the www or public web directory of your web server. Because if you are running your pages as a localhost the relative paths mostly starts from the folder within www or web directory example  if file is in 
/www/images/image.png

The relative path will be
src="/images/image.png"

Which means path according to local web address is
http://localhost/images/image.png

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to do that but its not working...should we need to add ip address infront of path?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should start by checking you path again

```
/home/Ubuntu/Chat/public/images/directions-icon.jpg
```

and

```
/home/Ubuntu/Chat-BOT/public/images/directions-icon.jpg
```

are not exactly the same.

You seem to be referencing `Chat-Bot` while you probably meant to reference `Chat` (or probably vice-versa)